# What is the recommended hardware for the following neo4j setup?

Tags: neo4j

I need to build and analyze a complex network using neo4j and would like to know what is the recommended hardware for the following setup:

1. There are three types of nodes.
2. There are three types of relationships.
3. At the steady state, the network will contain about 1M nodes of each type and about the same amount of edges
4. Every day, about 500K relationships are updated and 100K nodes and edges are added. Approximately the same amount of nodes/edges are also removed.
5. Network update will be done in daily batches and we can tolerate update times of 1-2 hours
6. Once the system is up, we will quire the database for shortest paths between different nodes. Not more than 500K times per day. We can live with batch query.

Most probably, I'll use REST API

Comment: What type of access are you using? REST api? embedded?

Comment: I'll use REST API (edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [Neo4j Hardware requirements](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-requirements.html).

For the server you're talking about, I think the first thing needed will obviously be a large bandwidth. If your requests are done in a short time, it'll be needed.

Apart from that, a "normal" server should be enough :

- 8 or more cores
- At least 24Go ram
- At least 1To SSD storage (this one is important and expensive)
- A good bandwidth (like 1Gbps)

By the way, it's not a programming question, so I think you should have asked this to [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/contact-us/).

Comment: Thank you. Neo4j "contact us" page mentioned SO. Do you think that this question should be migrated to http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: I think it would be a better place yes, using the neo4j tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Neo4j Hardware sizing calculator](http://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator/) for rough estimation of the HW needs.

Comment: What a usefull tool !